# What's this chinese symbol mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this Chinese symbol mean?

[image: What does this Chinese symbol mean?]

Comment: "不屈" ~ unyielding, or unbending. may i ask, don't you know the meaning of  it, before "put" it on your back?

Comment: it is on the chest, and the tattoo may not belong to the OP

Answer (score 0):

不屈：不屈服(于强大的对手) – unyielding, unbending

When you don't surrender to a strong enemy/opponent, you are 不屈的. This word is often used to describe heroes/heroines in wars and battles.

Answer (score 0):

不-非也(Means:Not!)
http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/fra/fra00010.htm
http://www.vividict.com/WordInfo.aspx?id=3673

屈-心意不順暢或彎曲身體部位(
There is something to force you to do what you do not want to do! Or Bend the body parts!)
http://dict.variants.moe.edu.tw/yitia/fra/fra01083.htm
http://www.vividict.com/WordInfo.aspx?id=1579

不屈-不屈服於某人或某事
(Not succumb to someone or something!)

Answer (score 0):

Chinese word 不屈 usually menas "never give up, never surrender" to describe someone that is very strong psychologically. The Chinese word is often used with 坚韧不屈or不屈不挠. Let us have an example as "狼有三大特性：一是敏锐的嗅觉；二是不屈不挠、奋不顾身的进攻精神；三是群体奋斗的意识。", "对于不屈不挠的人来说，没有失败这回事。" On the other hand，不屈has two parts of speech, one is used as a verb, for example "对于敌人的威逼利诱，他从不屈服。" The other is an adjective. For example "他虽然双腿残疾，但是他坚韧不屈的精神着实让我们感动”.

Answer (score 0):

It can be dated from the 《左传·襄公二十九年》：“至矣哉！直而不倨，曲而不屈。”I think it commonly to describe a strong mind and you will never change you dream, give up to tough environment or the powerful man.